# Simple Vehicle speed representation

Tags: performance, php, object-oriented, inheritance

This code models two vehicle types, with a method to accept a string representing a boost to change speed.

- How can I optimize performance in inheritance child class?
- How can I reduce the code inside BMW class?
- How can I use additional variables to reduce the child class code?

```
class Maruti{
     public $currentSpeed;
     
     public function __construct($speed){
        $this->currentSpeed = $speed;
     }
     public function increaseSpeed($boost){
        if($boost == 'bad'){
            $this->currentSpeed -=5;
        }elseif($boost == 'fair'){
             $this->currentSpeed +=5;
        }elseif($boost == 'good'){
             $this->currentSpeed +=10;
        }elseif($boost == 'turbo'){
            $this->currentSpeed +=20;
        }
        if($this->currentSpeed == 100 || $this->currentSpeed == 125 || $this->currentSpeed == 150){
            echo "Congratulations! You have reached a speed of $this->currentSpeed";
        }
     }    
}

class BMW extends Maruti{
    public function increaseSpeed($boost){
       if($boost == 'fair'){
             $this->currentSpeed +=10;
        }elseif($boost == 'good'){
             $this->currentSpeed +=15;
        }elseif($boost == 'turbo'){
            $this->currentSpeed +=25;
        }
        if($this->currentSpeed == 100 || $this->currentSpeed == 125 || $this->currentSpeed == 150){
            echo "Congratulations! You have reached a speed of $this->currentSpeed";
        }
     }    
}
 $obj = new BMW(115);
 $obj->increaseSpeed('fair');
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/264228/3) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

## Suggestions

Before addressing the main question, there are some suggestions to mention first.

### S.O.L.I.D. principles

If you aren't already familiar with them, look into the [SOLID principles](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual_articles/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design). The **S** is for the [Single-Responsibility Principle](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual_articles/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design#single-responsibility-principle):

> A class should have one and only one reason to change, meaning that a class should have only one job.

The `increaseSpeed()` methods violate this principle because they handle:

- updating the `currentSpeed` property
- outputting text based on the value of the `currentSpeed` property

the output of text should be handle elsewhere - e.g. a separate method, or in the code that interacts with the object.

### Formatting

Before I address the question, I would suggest considering readability. Have you looked as [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/)? The code adheres to it somewhat, except for a few recommendations like spacing for braces:

> The opening brace for the class MUST go on its own line; the closing brace for the class MUST go on the next line after the body.

I honestly am not fond of having an opening brace go on its own line, having worked with JS for many years, but it should at least have a space after the class name for readability:

```
class Maruti { 
          //^ adds separation
```

### Type hinting

"*Type declarations can be added to function arguments, return values, and, as of PHP 7.4.0, class properties. They ensure that the value is of the specified type at call time, otherwise a TypeError is thrown.*"<sup>[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php)</sup>

The constructors can expect `$speed` to be a numeric type - e.g. `int`, `float`, and the `increaseSpeed()` methods can expect `$boost` to be a string type - i.e. `string`.

Additionally return types for the methods can be declared. "*PHP 7 adds support for [return type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php).*"<sup>[2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations)</sup> and as of PHP 7.1 [`void`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.void-functions) can be used.

## Main Question

> #### How Can I reduce the code inside BMW class? How can I use additional variables to reduce the child class code?

One way to reduce the code is to define a mapping of strings to numbers to be added - e.g.

```
class Maruti {
    protected const BOOST_MAPPING = [
     'bad' => -5,
     'fair' => 5,
     'good' => 10,
     'turbo' => 20
    ];
```

Then in the `increaseSpeed` method check to see if that mapping contains a key at `$boost` (e.g. one can use [`isset()`](https://php.net/isset)) - if it does then add the value associated with that key within `static::BOOST_MAPPING`. Then check the value of the `currentSpeed` and if it is 100, 125 or 150 then echo the statement - hint: use [`in_array()`](https://php.net/in_array) to eliminate the *or* operators.

Then in the sub-class override the mapping, and then there will be no need to override the method `increaseSpeed()`

```
class BMW extends Maruti {
    protected const BOOST_MAPPING = [
     'fair' => 10,
     'good' => 15,
     'turbo' => 25
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need inheritance for this. you don't even need 2 classes since the only difference is a config.
Taking it from where [Sam got](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/264229/222948) I think you can do this:
(Also did some other changes as class methods should not `echo` something. You should always separate the logic from presentation layer)

```
class Car
{
    private int $currentSpeed;
    private array $boostMap;
    private array $targetSpeeds;
     
    public function __construct(int $speed, array $boostMap, array $targetSpeeds = [100, 125, 150])
    {
        $this->currentSpeed = $speed;
        $this->boostMap = $boostMap;
        $this->targetSpeeds = $targetSpeeds;
    }

    public function increaseSpeed(string $boost): void
    {
        $this->currentSpeed += ($this->boostMap[$boost] ?? 0);
    } 

    public function isTargetSpeedReached(): bool
    {
        return in_array($this->currentSpeed, $this->targetSpeeds);   
    }

    public function getCurrentSpeed(): int
    {
        return $this->currentSpeed;
    }
}
```

Now using the class.

```
$marutiBoostMap = [
    'bad' => -5,
    'fair' => 5,
    'good' => 10,
    'turbo' => 20
];
$maruti = new Car(20, $marutiBoostMap);
$maruti->increaseSpeed('good');
if ($maruti->isTargetSpeedReached()) {
    echo "Congratulations, you reached the speed " . $maruti->getCurrentSpeed();
}
```

You can do the same for bmw

```
$bmwBoostMap = [
    'fair' => 10,
    'good' => 15,
    'turbo' => 25
];
$bmw = new Car(20, $bmwBoostMap);
$bmw->increaseSpeed('good');
if ($bmw->isTargetSpeedReached()) {
    echo "Congratulations, you reached the speed " . $bmw->getCurrentSpeed();
}
```

You can use the code as it is if you need it for a car instance. Or you can use the code in a loop by reading the configs from and array of configs.

here is a random example on how you can take it further.

```
class CarFactory
{
    private array $config = [
        'maruti' => [
            'speed' => 10,
            'boostMap' => [
                'bad' => -5,
                'fair' => 5,
                'good' => 10,
                'turbo' => 20
             ]
        ],
        'bmw' => [
            'speed' => 20,
            'boostMap' => [
                'fair' => 10,
                'good' => 15,
                'turbo' => 25
            ]
        ]
    ];

    public function create(string $model): Car
    {
         $config = $this->config[$model] ?? null;
         if ($config === null) {
             throw new \InvalidArguemtException("Model {$model}" is not supported);
         }
         return new Car($config['speed'] ?? 0, $config['boostMap'] ?? []);
    }
}
```

then use this factory to create all kind of instances

```
$factory = new CarFactory();
$maruti = $factory->create('maruti');
$bmw = $factory->create('bmw');

//do your magic with $maruti and $bmw.
```